# Is there a way to pass data to a third party application from Salesforce?

Tags: community, third-party

Our client need to send a particular data from Salesforce to their server on a button click from Salesforce page.

We got solution using Connected App. But we need to initiate the data transfer from Salesforce. Is there an option to send data from Salesforce to our third party application directly on a button click or form submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use different [WebServices API SFDC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm) to do this.

You can use REST or SOAP to do this.

Comment: Above link is explaining about interacting with Other Salesforce REST APIs right? What we need is to send data from Salesforce to our own server. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you are going to use SOAP all you need is the WSDL from your system and to make some modifications in SFDC to access your system. If using REST you need a different approach like HTTP Methods to reach an endpoint (external system URL)  and do the correct operation like; POST, GET etc ...

Comment: But how secure it can be? We need to authenticate the data from Salesforce right? How can we set that up in Salesforce? Is there any tutorial or something explaining the process?

Comment: If you need to have a verification process it really depends on your business processes. Salesforce uses OAuth protocol, check more here "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm". It is very secure but I will suggest that you check those links. There are material that you can use to get start building integration solutions with SFDC, check Trailhead for integration services: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services

Comment: Ok. But this goes with Connected App right? Authentication flow starts from our server by requesting the Authentication code from Salesforce.

Comment: Yes, you use connected apps:  "When you develop an external application that needs to authenticate with Salesforce, you need to define it as a new connected app within the Salesforce organization that informs Salesforce of this new authentication entry point." REST API https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_defining_remote_access_applications.htm